# Retrieve picture from camera intent in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I am trying to open the Camera Intent and to retrieve the taken image to put it in an ImageView.

This was my **first attempt**:

```java
 fun cameraPic(view: View) {
     val cameraIntent = Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
     startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, 1001)
 }
```

```java
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && requestCode == 1001) {
        val ImageView = findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.selected_image);
        val photo = attr.data.get("data")
        ImageView.setImageBitmap(photo)
    }
}
```

This failed because `attr.data.get("data")` returns `null`.

So after doing some research, this was my **second attempt:**

```java
fun cameraPic(view: View) {
    val cameraIntent = Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
    startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, 1001)
}
```

```java
     override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && requestCode == 1001) {
            val ImageView = findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.selected_image);
            val photo = attr.data.get("data")
            ImageView.setImageBitmap(photo)


            // CALL THIS METHOD TO GET THE URI FROM THE BITMAP
            val tempUri = getImageUri(applicationContext, photo)

  
            // Show Uri path based on Image
            Toast.makeText(this, "Here $tempUri", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

     
            // Show Uri path based on Cursor Content Resolver
            Toast.makeText(this, "Real path for URI : " + getRealPathFromURI(tempUri), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }

    private fun getImageUri(applicationContext: Context, photo: Bitmap): Uri? {
        val bytes = ByteArrayOutputStream()
        photo.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes)
        val path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(this.getContentResolver(), photo, "Title", null)
        return Uri.parse(path)
    }

    fun getRealPathFromURI(uri: Uri?): String? {
        val cursor: Cursor? = contentResolver.query(uri!!, null, null, null, null)

        if (cursor == null) {
            return null;
        }

        cursor.moveToFirst()
        val idx: Int = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA)
        return cursor.getString(idx)
    }
```

This gives the error:

```
Unresolved reference. None of the following candidates is applicable because of receiver type mismatch: 
public inline operator fun <K, V> Map<out TypeVariable(K), TypeVariable(V)>.get(key: TypeVariable(K)): TypeVariable(V)? defined in kotlin.collections
```

for the line `val photo = attr.data.get("data")`.

So, how do I start the Camera intent, and display the taken picture in Kotlin Android?

Thanks!

Comment: "This failed because attr.data.get("data") returns null." -- what is `attr`? Should this be just `data.get("data")`?

Comment: No. It gives the same error.

Answer (score 0):

```
    private var photoFile: File? = null
lateinit var currentPhotoPath: String



private fun cameraPermission(){

    when{
        ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(requireContext(), android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED->{
            dispatchTakePictureIntent()
        }
        shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA)-> getActivity()?.let {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                it, arrayOf(android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA), REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSIONS)
        }

        else -> getActivity()?.let { ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(it, arrayOf(android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA), REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSIONS) }
    }
}

private fun dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
    val takePictureIntent = Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
    // Create the File where the photo should go
    photoFile = createImageFile()

    // Continue only if the File was successfully created
    if(photoFile != null){
        val photoURI: Uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(
            requireContext(),
            "com.billsAplication.fileprovider", // Your package
            photoFile!!)
        takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI)
    }

    if (requireContext().getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_ANY)) {
        // Start the image capture intent to take photo
        startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
    }

}


@SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat")
@Throws(IOException::class)
private fun createImageFile(): File {
    // Create an image file name
    val timeStamp: String = SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(Date())
    val storageDir: File? = requireContext().getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)
    return File.createTempFile(
        "JPEG_${timeStamp}_", /* prefix */
        ".jpg", /* suffix */
        storageDir /* directory */
    ).apply {
        // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
        currentPhotoPath = absolutePath
    }
}

override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        val imageBitmap =  BitmapFactory.decodeFile(photoFile!!.absolutePath)
        binding.imageView.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap)
    }
}
```